# USB 3.0 to gigabit ethernet keeps crashing system with 10.10.1/2

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, crash, ethernet

I have [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/2014-Amazing-USB-3-0-Gigabit-Ethernet-RJ45-External-Network-Card-LAN-Adapter-10-100-1000Mbps/32226474623.html) Realtek USB 3.0 to gigabit ethernet adaptor. Using either the included drivers for OS 10.8.x or the official Realtek drivers from December 2014, it hard crashes the system every 5-10 minutes. I have about 120 GiB of data to transfer to a 13" Pro Retina and no external HDD - is there a way to make the Realtek adaptor work under 10.10.x or a quicker way to transfer my data?

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth starting up in **Safe Boot** mode and then using a utility like Onyx to clear your system caches and see if that helps with your stability issues.

Otherwise can you not transfer wirelessly? It won't be as fast as GB Ethernet but it would still get the job done. Failing that I'd suggest either an Apple Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter, or a USB transfer cable like [this](http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/USB-PS2/USB-to-USB-Data-Transfer-Cable-for-Windows-and-Mac~PCMACLINK) (probably *much* cheaper than the Apple adapter).